# How do I get Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, 15.10

I was following the instructions on here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts but every time I do `sudo apt-get update`, I run into a message that ends with

```
100% [1 Packages bzip2 0 B] [27 InRelease gpgv 1,855 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] 
[WaSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.ubuntu.com_xenial_libpcre2-dev_dists_wily_InRelease 
into data and signature faIgn http://packages.ubuntu.com wily InRelease                                                                                
E: GPG error: http://packages.ubuntu.com wily InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I think this means that there's something up with my libpcre2, which I remember I had to install in a really hacky way that I can't remember any of the details from. But in any case I can't seem to get my apt-get to detect that 16.04 exists. How can I get apt-get update to ignore my libpcre2 or uninstall it so I can reinstall it when the upgrade to 16.04 is complete?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of it do:

1. Open `system settings --> Software & Updates --> Other software`
2. Click on the repo in question and click remove. See image below:

   [image]
3. Software & Updates will updated the repo list and then go ahead and try that upgrade.